# Finding the dual cone of $\Omega_1=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_2\geq 0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, inner-products

I am trying to find the dual cone of $$\Omega_1=\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x_2\geq 0\}.$$
Let $K$ be a convex cone in an inner product space $H$. Then the dual cone,$\ K^*$, is defined by $$K^*=\{x\in H:\langle z,x\rangle\geq 0 \ \ \forall z\in K\}.$$
I am having difficulty visualising what the dual cone should look like, if the cone is the upper half-plane.

Comment: Geometric intuition for what you are asking is: which vectors in the plane form an angle of not more than $90^\circ$ with *all* vectors in $\Omega_1$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Ahhh I see. So the vertical axes must be in the dual.

Comment: So the dual cone is the origin, right? Or is it the empty set?